# How can I set a max line length in vscode texStudio? for source code formatting

Tags: texstudio

It is very annoying that lines go to infinity esp when coming from Overleaf. I am open to solutions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this related to VSCode or to TeXStudio? You should probably look for the settings for word wrap. For VSCode, maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31025502/9303652

Comment: that may do, I will have a look!